# Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip'

Tags: java, android, gradle

Can anyone help me on this error

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip'.
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
You can try some of the following options:
  - changing the IDE settings.
  - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

**1- update the gradle:**

Get latest version supported by Android Studio from:

https://services.gradle.org/distributions

**2- upgrade an Android project to Java 11:**

```
android {
    .
    .
    .
    compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    // For Kotlin projects
    kotlinOptions {
      jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
```

Go to Preferences → Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle → *Gradle JDK.

[image]

**3- Sync Project:**

- Sync project
- Clean Project
- Rebuild Project

That's it.